# VBA Vlookup-Type mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

I have an vlookup code it is working fine in my excel 2019, but when try to run the same code on my office PC it throws me an Type mismatch error. I have spend a lot of time to find solution but I can't.

Below is the following Code

```
Sub Vlookup()
  Dim lookfor As Variant
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim MaturedPolicies As Variant
  A = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("SQL Results").Range("$B:$B"))
  lookfor = Sheets("SQL Results").Range("B2:B" & A).Value
  Set rng = Sheets("SQL Results").Range("$Y$2:$Y$100")
  MaturedPolicies = Application.WorksheetFunction.Vlookup(lookfor, rng, 1, 
False)

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Sheets("SQL Results").Range("W2:W" & A).Value = MaturedPolicies
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Seems to works fine in Excel 2016.  Are you using the exact same spread sheet or did you copy paste the code into a different workbook?

Comment: This may be down to the data. It sounds like some sort of casting issue. Putting string into number etc. Have you tried opening exact same spreadsheet from both machines? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/vartype-function - try a MsgBox on VarType(lookfor)  and other data. See if you can debug issue.

Comment: Also you may be able to debug from Type Mismatch - according to this link https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-type-mismatch/

Comment: No, i just copy paste the code i do not open the exact same spreadsheet. What should i d..? i am in trouble can anyone write a new code base on the above code which can work irrespective of excels versions.

Comment: I agree with JGFMK, it doesn't sound like an Excel version issue but a data issue.  Text instead of number for example.  What line does the debugger highlight when the error happens?

Comment: it highlights the following line                                                                                                       MaturedPolicies = Application.WorksheetFunction.Vlookup(lookfor, rng, 1, 
False)

Comment: can you `Debug.Print lookfor` and tell us the value? The vlookup you are doing where it errors relates back to this point

Comment: When i type msg box Vartype(lookfor) is get 8204